# Difference between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n_i}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $x_i, y_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n_i}$, where $x_i$ and $y_i$ are vectors. I know $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the space of all n-dimensional vectors, so what does $\mathbb{R}^{n_i}$ denote?

Comment: $n_i$ is a positive integer, so $x_i$ denotes a tuple with $n_i$ many entries.

Comment: It is common in mathematics to consider a set of several natural numbers and index them in some way. For example, if I have the spaces $\mathbb{R}^5$ and $\mathbb{R}^7$ and I want to say that they are non-empty spaces, I can say $\mathbb{R}^{n_i}$, for $ i\in\{1,2\}$, is non-empty, if I have previously defined that $n_1=5$ and $n_2=7$ or $n_1=7$ and $n_2=5$. Therefore, $n_i$ is just a natural number.

Comment: Although it is not clear, I presume that they are implicitly saying that the choice of $x_i,y_i$ may have different dimensions